# entity framework not generating second orderby

Tags: .net, entity-framework, mysql-connector

My problem is that I am trying to make 2 `OrderBy` but the second one is never generated for entity framework, I inspected the generated query.

This is what I am trying to do

```
 var query = model.SomeTable.Where(condition);
 if (somecondition)
     query = query.OrderByDescending(o => o.Table1.Col1).OrderBy(c => c.Table1.Table2.SomeColumn);
 var result = query.Select(c => new 
                             {
                                 //selection here
                             });
```

Order by for `Table1.Table2.SomeColumn` is generated, but the second OrderBy `Table1.Col1` is never generated and consequently my results are wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use OrderBY and ThenBy Combination.. i.e.:

```
query = query.OrderByDescending(o => o.Table1.Col1)
             .ThenBy(c => c.Table1.Table2.SomeColumn);
```